# Eclipse: Tips for archiving old projects together into a root project/folder?

Tags: java, eclipse

After a semester of work, my Eclipse package explorer is rather cluttered because it looks something like:

```
CS402-HW1
CS402-HW2
CS402-HW3
.
.
.

CS402-Group Project
CS 432-HW1
CS 432-HW2
CS 432-HW3
.
.
.
CS 432-Project
```

Now that I'm done with the classes, I want root folders/projects called CS402 and CS 432 that holds all the related projects.

I started by creating a new project called CS402, then right click one of the projects I want to achieve, say CS402-HW1, and I click refactor > move. I move it into a new subfolder named CS402-HW1 within the main CS402 project. Then in package explorer, I delete the project CS402-HW1 (just the project, not the files) since I can now see the project in the root CS402 project that I just moved it to.

Pretty sure I'm doing it wrong because now when I go in my package explorer under CS402 > CS 402-HW1 > src and try to run my .java files, it say unable to launch because there are no recent launches.

I think I'm not heading the right direction and I think I'm doing a horrible job at explaining my wrong doing, so I'll leave my question open ended...

In the package explorer, how would you go about archiving a bunch of projects together into 1 project or root folder?

Comment: If you store your projects in a version control system (like git) this situation changes vastly.  I would strongly recommend you learn this - it might also save your project up to a deadline if your computer breaks down or worse as the source is available elsewhere too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a 'working set' to group multiple projects into a collapsible item.

Comment: Thank you, never knew about working set and it seems perfect for what I need.

Comment: Glad to help.  There are some good tutorials that show how to create them, show them in the package explorer or navigator, etc..  Just to have something inline with the thread, a straight forward one is [link](http://alagad.com/2007/10/29/using-eclipse-working-sets-instead-of-workspaces)

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse Select Multiple Project You want to Archive than Right Click and Click On `Export` It will Open Dialog Box Select *(Or Write)* `Archive File` and click Next Enter Name Of Archive File Or Browse if you want it to store in already existing archive file like `.zip,.rar` ets. Click Finish.

*Right Click and Export Select Archive Files*

[image]

*Select Projects you want to Export*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screens, this is useful stuff I didn't know before but I went with the other answer because working set seems to work more with what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I always just:

1) Do a simple filecopy of my individual project(s) root folder, and everything underneath

2) Pack into a .zip file and backup the .zip somwwhere (for example, a removable TB disk)

3) Delete the project using Eclipse (specify "delete from disk=Y")

You can always go back re-import the archived .zip project into a new Eclipse workspace any time you want.

Comment: Good point, but the reason I was trying to keep the projects in my workspace is in case I want to run them again later I can easily do so without having to re-import whatever I want to look at.